# ¿Como aplicar zoom y centrar imagen de perfil?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, ccs

En Laravel tengo un formulario para el perfil del usuario.
En este formulario el usuario puede seleccionar una imágen para su propio perfil.
**Una ves que el usuario selecciona una imagen de alguna manera tengo que poder aplicarle zoom a la imagen y centrar la imagen.**
Por ejemplo: si selecciono está imagen

[image: usuario]

**Después de aplicarle zoom, mover la imagen hasta centrarla debería de poder verse perfectamente aquí:**

[image: perfil]

**Lo que prendiendo es enfocar el rostro del usuario.**
Entonces como puedo resolver este inconveniente? Existe algún plugin ?

Comment: Y tu código? Por favor revisa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JheymanMejia la única funcionalidad implementada que tengo con código es la de seleccionar una imagen y guardar dicha imagen. Para lo que busco no tengo funcionalidad, no tengo código, por eso mismo hice una pregunta general preguntando si es que existe algún plugin para lo que necesito, me explico?